# Display javascript as code snippet

Tags: javascript, html, css, prettify

What I'm trying to do is display a snippet of javascript on the page, and not have it run, just display as a code snippet for folks to copy. I load google's Prettify, then in the page I have this code:

```
    <pre class="prettyprint">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('deleting cookie');
        $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain});
     },1000);
    });
    </script>
   </pre>
```

But this code just executes and doesn't display the JS snippet. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try viewing the source HTML of this question, that'd show you one way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to convert your `<` and `>` characters to HTML entities like so:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
  &lt;script&gt;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('deleting cookie');
        $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain});
      },1000);
    });
  &lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

I would also recommend wrapping the code in `<code>` tags in addition to the existing `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is that you are entering HTML and you want it to not be treated as HTML.  Specifically, the opening `<script>` element.

In order to enter HTML that will not be parsed as HTML, you need to encode characters that are special to HTML.  For instance `<` is encoded as `&lt;`, `>` is encoded as `&gt;`, and `&` is encoded as `&amp;`.

So, to output the following without it being parsed as HTML:

```
<script>...</script>
```

...you need to enter:

```
&lt;script&gt;...&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's running because of the `<script>` tags.  You should encode them:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
&lt;script&gt;
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('deleting cookie');
    $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain});
 },1000);
});
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `&lt;script&gt;` and `&lt;/script&gt;` for `<script>` tag

Answer (score -1):

Let the `textContent` property (or `createTextNode`) do all the heavy lifting of encoding whatever text you need to insert into dom:

```
var sampleCode="<script> $(document).ready(function(){ setTimeout(function(){ console.log('deleting cookie'); $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain}); },1000); }); </script>";
var pre=document.createElement("pre");
pre.textContent=sampleCode;
pre.className="prettyprint";
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```