# prevent html code from being executed

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a webpage, and I have some javascript code for a countdown timer. below the timer, I want to show people the code for the project without forcing them to open developer tools, so I made the following:

```
<body onload="show()">
    <span id="showCode">
        <!-- where I want my code to show -->
    </span>
    <script>

    function show() {
        document.getElementById('showCode').innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    </script>
</body>
```

How can I use javascript to show the inner html of an element instead of executing the code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'll update the question with an actual question

Comment: How about using the <xmp> tag? Use Javascript to wrap your HTML code with this tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545/what-was-the-xmp-tag-used-for

Comment: I just changed the `<span>` tags into `<xmp>` tags and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

"You need to convert your `<` and `>` characters to HTML entities like so:"

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
  &lt;script&gt;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('deleting cookie');
        $.cookie('cookie',null,{domain: document.domain});
      },1000);
    });
  &lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

"I would also recommend wrapping the code in `<code>` tags in addition to the existing `<pre>` tags."

~ [Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307338/travis)

[Display javascript as code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753241/display-javascript-as-code-snippet)

Comment: I am not sure if this will work for you or if you are trying to do more then just display the countdown code.

Comment: it would work for what I am doing right now, but I wan't to use this code for other purposes. I wan't to be able to set the innerHTML of an element to code as a string. This would be useful for something like a webpage builder that shows the current code for the webpage.