# Displaying a block of code in react project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to display code samples of different languages on a website built using react.

Ideally the code sample maintains its formatting and includes line numbers.
Best case scenario would be to include syntax highlighting based on the language.

Any suggestions on how to approach this is appreciated.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow "javascrpit library code snippet" in google will help you. Or maybe you wanna do it all about yourself ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display javascript as code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753241/display-javascript-as-code-snippet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [react-syntax-highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter)

```
npm install react-syntax-highlighter --save
```

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { docco } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';
const Component = () => {
  const codeString = '(num) => num + 1';
  return (
    <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={docco}>
      {codeString}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>
  );
};
```